# Visualforce pageBlockSection with 2 columns

Tags: visualforce

I have this Visualforce code:

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Carry Over" columns="2">

        <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}"/>

        <apex:repeat value="{!carryoverBuckets}" var="bucket">
            <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}" />     
            <apex:inputField label="Carryover Period {!cnt} amount" value="{!bucket.Amount__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!bucket.Expiry_Date__c}" required="false"/>  
        </apex:repeat>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

which is supposed to render inputfields along with their labels in 2 columns.

This works OK if I remove the `<apex:variable/>` tags and the `{!cnt}` from the label, but with those in place, the layout is broken.

If I use `rendered="false"` on the `<apex:variable/>` tags, then layout is restored, but the value of `{!cnt}` is not rendered, or is empty.

How can I correct the layout, and retain the value of `{!cnt}`?

Comment: When you say broken is the field not showing up on the VF page?can you post screenshot?

Comment: try to use `apex:pageblocksectionItem`